# Angular Switching Header According to Id

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a screen which I use for different elements. In this screen, I have a table. I want to change one of the columns' header according to the SourceType. When I try that like I've written below, it gives an error. What should I do, use to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="DeliveryNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef *ngIf="_stockEntry.SourceType != 49"> Tesellüm No </th>
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef *ngIf="_stockEntry.SourceType == 49"> Parti No </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                <span *ngIf="EditIndex != i">{{row.DeliveryNumber}}</span>
                <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p">
                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="row.DeliveryNumber" required name="DeliveryNumber">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of deliveryList" [value]="prm.DeliveryNumber">
                            {{prm.DeliveryNumber}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: what kind of error do you have ?

Comment: `core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with *`

Comment: @TreacleMark the problem is in this line `*matHeaderCellDef *ngIf`

Comment: What should I do? @GRD

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple structural directives (`*ngIf` & `*matHeaderCellDef` )  on one element. So what you can do is having `ngIf` on a `ng-container` :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="DeliveryNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > 
        <ng-container *ngIf="_stockEntry.SourceType !== 49">Tesellüm No </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="_stockEntry.SourceType == 49">Parti No </ng-container>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
        <span *ngIf="EditIndex != i">{{row.DeliveryNumber}}</span>
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p">
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="row.DeliveryNumber" required name="DeliveryNumber">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of deliveryList" [value]="prm.DeliveryNumber">
                    {{prm.DeliveryNumber}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```